# How to get a map or list of template 'actions' from a parsed template?

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

So I would like to somehow get all of my `{{ .blahblah }}` actions defined in a template as slice of strings.

For example if I have this template:

```
<h1>{{ .name }} {{ .age }}</h1>
```

I would like to be able to get `[]string{"name", "age"}`. Pretend that a template has the method `func (t *Template) Fields() []string`:

```
t := template.New("cooltemplate").Parse(`<h1>{{ .name }} {{ .age }}</h1>`)
if t.Fields() == []string{"name", "age"} {
    fmt.Println("Yay, now I know what fields I can pass in!")
    // Now lets pass in the name field that we just discovered.
    _ = t.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]string{"name": "Jack", "age":"120"})
}
```

Is there a way to inspect a parsed template like this?
Thanks!

Comment: A template contains a parse.Tree which exposes this kind of stuff (FieldNode). Form the docs: "The *parse.Tree field is exported only for use by html/template and should be treated as unexported by all other clients." So: Don't do that. If you do not follow that advice: Good luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Foreword: As Voker suggests, the `Template.Tree` field is *"exported only for use by html/template and should be treated as unexported by all other clients."*

You should not rely on such thing to be able to provide input for a template execution. You must know the template you want to execute along with the data it expects. You shouldn't "explore" it at runtime to provide arguments for it.

---

The value you get out of parsing a template is [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template) (either `text/template` or `html/template`, they have the same API). This template represents the templates as a tree of type [`parse.Tree`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/parse/#Tree). Everything that a text template contains is stored in this tree in nodes, including static texts, actions etc.

Having said that, you can walk this tree and look for nodes that identify such actions that access fields or call functions. The nodes are of type [`parse.Node`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/parse/#Node) which has a `Node.Type()` method returning its type. The possible types are defined as constants in the `parse` package, next to the [`parse.NodeType`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/parse/#NodeType) type, e.g.

```
const (
        NodeText    NodeType = iota // Plain text.
        NodeAction                  // A non-control action such as a field evaluation.
        NodeBool                    // A boolean constant.
        NodeChain                   // A sequence of field accesses.
        NodeCommand                 // An element of a pipeline.
        NodeDot                     // The cursor, dot.

        NodeField      // A field or method name.
        NodeIdentifier // An identifier; always a function name.
        NodeIf         // An if action.
        NodeList       // A list of Nodes.
        NodeNil        // An untyped nil constant.
        NodeNumber     // A numerical constant.
        NodePipe       // A pipeline of commands.
        NodeRange      // A range action.
        NodeString     // A string constant.
        NodeTemplate   // A template invocation action.
        NodeVariable   // A $ variable.
        NodeWith       // A with action.
)
```

So here is an example program that recursively walks a template tree, and looks for nodes with `NodeAction` type, which is *"A non-control action such as a field evaluation."*

This solution is just a demonstration, a proof of concept, it does not handle all cases.

```
func ListTemplFields(t *template.Template) []string {
    return listNodeFields(t.Tree.Root, nil)
}

func listNodeFields(node parse.Node, res []string) []string {
    if node.Type() == parse.NodeAction {
        res = append(res, node.String())
    }

    if ln, ok := node.(*parse.ListNode); ok {
        for _, n := range ln.Nodes {
            res = listNodeFields(n, res)
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Example using it:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("cooltemplate").
    Parse(`<h1>{{ .name }} {{ .age }}</h1>`))
fmt.Println(ListTemplFields(t))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YjcFtjRVIS)):

```
[{{.name}} {{.age}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify, the reason you would want to get the actions at runtime is if you are not in control of the template creation, or the template changes frequently. For example I have templates representing letters. I have a GUI that allows a user to input values for the template. Obviously every template will have some similar and some different actions that need to be filled. So the GUI needs to be able to display input boxes for every action found on a template at runtime, otherwise I would have to statically code in the all the input boxes for every single template.

Comment: Similar to @JackMordaunt, I built a tool for template processing. But the designer of a template must provide a manifest of action names to the user of the template. To aid the designer, who knows all the actions and has to manually build the manifest;  I added a sub command that will generate the manifest because they are likely to forget 1 or 2. Again the client does not use this, but the designer of the tool does to reduce human error. Hopefully a good exception to the rule.

Comment: Exactly, this is super useful for user-defined templates. It allows users to create and submit templates, and for the backend to figure out which things need injecting into the template without having to build a monolithic `map[string]any` that contains every possible thing the user might want

Answer (score 2):

A small optimization to @icza 's answer, maybe it helps a little :)

```golang
func listNodeFieldsV2(node parse.Node) []string {
    var res []string
    if node.Type() == parse.NodeAction {
        res = append(res, node.String())
    }
    if ln, ok := node.(*parse.ListNode); ok {
        for _, n := range ln.Nodes {
            res = append(res, listNodeFieldsV2(n)...)
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Note you can get a list of `{{template "name"}}` by using `parse.NodeTemplate` instead of `parse.NodeAction`

Answer (score 0):

I have happened to need roughly the same code.
In my use case, we allow users to create templates on one side, and to enter a `map[string]string` of variables to be used for rendering in a different form.

This is the code that I came up with so far (inspired by icza's answer):

```
// Extract the template vars required from *simple* templates.
// Only works for top level, plain variables. Returns all problematic parse.Node as errors.
func RequiredTemplateVars(t *template.Template) ([]string, []error) {
    var res []string
    var errors []error
    var ln *parse.ListNode
    ln = t.Tree.Root
Node:
    for _, n := range ln.Nodes {
        if nn, ok := n.(*parse.ActionNode); ok {
            p := nn.Pipe
            if len(p.Decl) > 0 {
                errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("Node %v not supported", n))
                continue Node
            }
            for _, c := range p.Cmds {
                if len(c.Args) != 1 {
                    errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("Node %v not supported", n))
                    continue Node
                }
                if a, ok := c.Args[0].(*parse.FieldNode); ok {
                    if len(a.Ident) != 1 {
                        errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("Node %v not supported", n))
                        continue Node
                    }
                    res = append(res, a.Ident[0])
                } else {
                    errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("Node %v not supported", n))
                    continue Node
                }

            }
        } else {
            if _, ok := n.(*parse.TextNode); !ok {
                errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("Node %v not supported", n))
                continue Node
            }
        }
    }
    return res, errors
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nH95B45jUmI

Answer (score 0):

solution for search variables in template, with reflect + template

```
func parseTemplateVariables(template string) {
    parsedTemplate, err := text_template.New("test").Option("missingkey=error").Parse(template)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    visited := make(map[interface{}]bool)
    queue := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(parsedTemplate.Root)}
    for len(queue) != 0 {
        node := queue[0]
        queue = queue[1:]

        for node.Kind() != reflect.Struct && node.Kind() != reflect.Array && node.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
            node = node.Elem()
        }

        if node.CanInterface() {
            vInterface := node.Interface()
            if listNode, ok := vInterface.([]parse.Node); ok {
                for _, itemNode := range listNode {
                    if itemNode.Type() == parse.NodeField {
                        log.Printf("using variable: %v", itemNode)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var n int
        if node.Kind() == reflect.Array || node.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            n = node.Len()
        } else {
            n = node.NumField()
        }
        for i := 0; i != n; i++ {
            var itemNode reflect.Value
            if node.Kind() == reflect.Array || node.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
                itemNode = node.Index(i)
            } else {
                itemNode = node.Field(i)
            }

            if !itemNode.IsValid() || itemNode.IsZero() {
                continue
            }

            if itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Bool ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.String ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int8 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int16 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int32 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int64 ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint8 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint16 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint32 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint64 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uintptr ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Float32 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Float64 ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Complex64 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Complex128 {
                continue
            }

            k := itemNode.Kind()
            _ = k

            if itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Array || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
                itemNodePtr := itemNode.Addr()
                if _, ok := visited[itemNodePtr]; ok {
                    continue
                }
                visited[itemNodePtr] = true
                //log.Printf("%v", itemNodePtr)
            } else {
                itemNodePtr := itemNode.Addr()
                if _, ok := visited[itemNodePtr]; ok {
                    continue
                }
                visited[itemNodePtr] = true
                //log.Printf("%v", itemNodePtr)
            }

            queue = append(queue, itemNode)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution for find variables, with reflect + template

```
func parseTemplateVariables(template string) {
    parsedTemplate, err := text_template.New("test").Option("missingkey=error").Parse(template)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    visited := make(map[interface{}]bool)
    queue := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(parsedTemplate.Root)}
    for len(queue) != 0 {
        node := queue[0]
        queue = queue[1:]

        for node.Kind() != reflect.Struct && node.Kind() != reflect.Array && node.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
            node = node.Elem()
        }

        if node.CanInterface() {
            vInterface := node.Interface()
            if listNode, ok := vInterface.([]parse.Node); ok {
                for _, itemNode := range listNode {
                    if itemNode.Type() == parse.NodeField {
                        log.Printf("using variable: %v", itemNode)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var n int
        if node.Kind() == reflect.Array || node.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            n = node.Len()
        } else {
            n = node.NumField()
        }
        for i := 0; i != n; i++ {
            var itemNode reflect.Value
            if node.Kind() == reflect.Array || node.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
                itemNode = node.Index(i)
            } else {
                itemNode = node.Field(i)
            }

            if !itemNode.IsValid() || itemNode.IsZero() {
                continue
            }

            if itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Bool ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.String ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int8 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int16 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int32 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Int64 ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint8 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint16 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint32 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uint64 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Uintptr ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Float32 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Float64 ||
                itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Complex64 || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Complex128 {
                continue
            }

            k := itemNode.Kind()
            _ = k

            if itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Array || itemNode.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
                itemNodePtr := itemNode.Addr()
                if _, ok := visited[itemNodePtr]; ok {
                    continue
                }
                visited[itemNodePtr] = true
                //log.Printf("%v", itemNodePtr)
            } else {
                itemNodePtr := itemNode.Addr()
                if _, ok := visited[itemNodePtr]; ok {
                    continue
                }
                visited[itemNodePtr] = true
                //log.Printf("%v", itemNodePtr)
            }

            queue = append(queue, itemNode)
        }
    }
}
```