# How to check if a line or string contains, to be templated variables in Golang?

Tags: go, templating

I have code like below

```
t, err := template.New("todos").Parse("You have a task named \"{{ .Name}}\" with description: \"{{ .Description}}\"")
```

Before I set the values of `Name` and `Description`, I have to check what are the defined templated variables in the line `"You have a task named \"{{ .Name}}\" with description: \"{{ .Description}}\""`. This line is user defined. So, I won't know what would be the template variables before hand.

Any other way without using Regex?

Thanks

Comment: The template's [parse tree](https://godoc.org/text/template/parse#Tree) can be used to find the field references.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to get a map or list of template 'actions' from a parsed template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584612/how-to-get-a-map-or-list-of-template-actions-from-a-parsed-template/40584967#40584967).But you should not rely on such thing to be able to provide input for a template execution. You must know the template you want to execute along with the data it expects. You shouldn't "explore" it at runtime to provide arguments for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have probably used a regex for it, but you can also avoid it using the parse result, like [@Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%C3%B3n) said. A solution could look something like this.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "text/template"
    "text/template/parse"
)

func main() {

    t, err := template.New("todos").Parse("You have a task named \"{{ .Name}}\" with description: \"{{ .Description}}\"")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, node := range t.Root.Nodes {
        if (node.Type() == parse.NodeAction) {
            log.Println(node.String())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jan. Agree that we could use Regex but just checking if something is already available