# Go template list variable to replace from template

Tags: go, go-templates

So I'm using go template and I would like to be able to generate a configmap dynamically by getting the list of the variable from the template.

To be precise, let's say I have a file name **test.yaml.tmpl** that looks something like that:

```
car:
  color: {{ .color }}
  model: {{ .model }}
```

I would like to be able to generate an array in my go code containing `[color model]` or `[.color .model]` , I can work with the dots myself.

I looked at the differents options but I could not get the result I want, the closest I got was using `template.Root.Nodes` to extract the variable value but it's not perfect and may generate unwanted error in specific conditions.

Does someone has a clean way to generate an array of the template variable?

**EDIT 1**

I tried to use the tree, and that gives me this type of output:

```
&{test.yaml.tmpl test.yaml.tmpl ---
car:
  color: {{ .color }}
  model: {{ .model }}
 0 ---
car:
  color: {{ .color }}
  model: {{ .model }}
[] <nil> [{8 995  45} {11 409 {{ 22} {0 0  0}] 1 [] map[] 0 0}
```

The issue is that I don't get to access the fields node the only methods available when accessing the tree are:

- ErrorContext
- Parse
- Copy and it's methods
- Mode
- Name
- ParseName
- Root and the NodeType method

Still can't get the list of fields.

**EDIT 2**

When printing the tree.Root.Nodes I get the full yaml output with the variables to replace like that:

```
(*parse.ActionNode)(0xc00007f1d0)({{ .color }}),
 (*parse.TextNode)(0xc00007f200)
```

Comment: Scan the  [parse tree](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.Tree) for [field nodes](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template/parse@go1.16.4#FieldNode).

Comment: I don't see how to access the field nodes, I tried the tempalte.Tree but I can't access field nodes like that, could you give an example please?

Comment: Ok, I edited with what I get and the available methods I have for it.

Comment: `t.Tree.Root.Nodes` is the list of root nodes.  These nodes contain other nodes.  [Spew](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew) an example [tree](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.Tree) with [methods disabled](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew#ConfigState.DisabledMethods) to learn about the structure of the tree.  I am not giving a more specific answer because I don't recall the details.

Comment: See related / possible duplicate: [How to get a map or list of template 'actions' from a parsed template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584612/how-to-get-a-map-or-list-of-template-actions-from-a-parsed-template/40584967#40584967)

Comment: Seems like the method works, at least as well as the solution with a regexp, maybe a bit more precise.

Comment: The only issue is that it give the content of limiters, with them in it so I would have to add   additional treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can user regex you know. ;P

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var fieldSearch = regexp.MustCompile(`{{ \..* }}`)

func main() {
    template := `
car:
  color: {{ .color }}
  model: {{ .model }}
`
    res := fieldSearch.FindAll([]byte(template), -1)
    for i := range res {
        // this is just for readability you can replace this with 
        // magic numbers if you want
        res[i] = res[i][len("{{ .") : len(res[i])-len(" }}")]
    }

    for _, v := range res {
        fmt.Println(string(v))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know... I'm currently doing something like this but with a bit more tweeking, because your method doesn't take into account the other argument like: or, if etc... So it's quite difficult to use correctly and I would like to do something cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I used the link posted by @icza  [How to get a map or list of template 'actions' from a parsed template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584612/how-to-get-a-map-or-list-of-template-actions-from-a-parsed-template/40584967#40584967)and treated the returned string to get what I need, this resulted in the following:

```
func main() {
    node := listNodeFields(t.Tree.Root)
    var tNode []string
    for _, n := range node {
        r := n[len("{{.* .") : len(n)-len(" .*}}")]
        if strings.Contains(n, "or ") {
            r = r + " or"
        }
        tNode = append(tNode, r)
    }

    config := make(map[string]string)
    for _, n := range tNode {
        var value string
        var present bool
        if strings.Contains(n, " or") {
            n = strings.Replace(n, " or", "", -1)
            value, present = os.LookupEnv(n)
            if !present {
                fmt.Println("The variable " + value + " is not set but there is a default value in template " + t.Name() + "!")
            }
        } else {
            value, present = os.LookupEnv(n)
            if !present {
                return nil, errors.New("The variable " + f + " is not set but exists in the template " + t.Name() + "!")
            }
        }
        config[n] = value
    }
}

func listNodeFields(node parse.Node) []string {
    var res []string
    if node.Type() == parse.NodeAction {
        res = append(res, node.String())
    }
    if ln, ok := node.(*parse.ListNode); ok {
        for _, n := range ln.Nodes {
            res = append(res, listNodeFields(n)...)
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

As I don't want to generate errors in case I'm using default value I added a specific treatment to not get errors from the missingkey=error option of the template.