# How to test if a Go template block is defined?

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm using Go 1.19 with the built-in HTML template engine. Is there a way to test if a block is defined in a particular template file?

Specifically, I want to implement optional header entries in the Go HTML template.

I have a general layout template that includes a content template when rendered.

I want to implement as below...

Currently, the `<meta name="description" content="{{block "description" .}}{{end}}">` result in an empty description tag. I'd like to not have the tag at all if there is nothing in it.

Any ideas?

layout.gohtml (simplified)[updated]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{block "title" .}}The Title{{end}}</title>
    {{if .renderDescription}}
        <meta name="description" content="{{template "description"}}">
    {{end}
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    {{template "content" .}}
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

content1.gohtml

```
{{define "title"}}The 2hO Network{{end}}
{{define "description"}}An options description{{end}}
{{define "content"}}
    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus...
{{end}}
```

content2.gohtml

```
{{define "title"}}The 2hO Network{{end}}
{{define "content"}}
    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus...
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates are designed to be statically analyzable. This means if you don't have a `description` template, you'll get an error when parsing the templates.

Instead use an `{{if}}` action to check if the `description` template needs to be rendered. The `description` template maybe empty.

For example:

```
{{if .renderDescription}}
    {{template "description"}}
{{end}}

{{define "description"}}description content{{end}}
```

If you have to check the `.renderDescription` in many places, you may also move the check (the `{{if}}` action) into the template, so you can unconditionally use `{{template}}` (but you still have to provide a pipeline that contains the condition):

```
{{template "description" .}}


{{define "description"}}
    {{if .renderDescription}}
        description content
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

**Notes:**

The `{{block}}` action is not to include a template, it is to *define* and *include* a template. To include a template defined elsewhere, use `{{template}}`.

You also have to change your template structuring. Instead of having a "frame" template embedding a "content", define "header" and "footer" templates, and have each page have its own template, which include "header", the content and "footer".

Comment: Thanks. But, I think you misunderstood the question... I have a block that may or may not be defined in a nested template. When it is defined, I wish to wrap the block in a tag. When it is not defined, I wish to skip the tag, avoiding the empty tag...

Comment: And as for the layout template wrapping the content, it works fine. You just have to parse them manually in code and store the result in a slice. i.e. you cannot rely on the template name as they will all be called "layout".

Comment: @PrecisionPete I understood your question. But again, when you parse templates, if a template is missing, a `{{template}}` action will cause parsing to fail (return an error). You used `{{block}}`, that's why it didn't fail for you. `{{block}}` is **not** to include a template defined elsewhere, it's to define a template _and_ execute it in place. It's short for `{{define}}` followed by a `{{template}}` action.

Comment: Can you please explain where the `.renderDescription` came from? I can't seem to get that to work. If I could, it would solve the problem nicely. In mine, it just comes out blank. Not true or false. e.g. `<{{.renderDescription}}>` renders as `<>`.

Comment: `renderDescription` needs to be passed as a template param. Your Go code has to determine if rendering description is required, and pass this boolean info as `"renderDescription"`.

Comment: So in the render routine, how do you detect if it's in the template? i.e. how do you detect it? search for a string?

Comment: You must know the template you're executing, and provide proper parameters needed for its execution. Go templates are not designed for dynamic analysis, for details see [How to get a map or list of template 'actions' from a parsed template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584612/how-to-get-a-map-or-list-of-template-actions-from-a-parsed-template/40584967#40584967)